# SpaCy - TextCategorizer - Bag Of Words: Is there a way to show the vectorized document?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, text-classification, spacy-3

I just trained and implemented a text categorizer using Space 3.0. Everything went smooth but I'd like to visualize the vectorized document (`[13, 0, 0, 120..etc]`) in order to better understand what feature (words) drove the bag-of-words (BoW) model to classify the document in a specific class.

```
nlp = spacy.load('./nlp_single_label_cli/output/model-best')    
documents = pd.read_csv(target_directory+'_ocr.csv')
...
test_texts = documents['text'].values
test_docs = [nlp.tokenizer(text) for text in test_texts]

text_categorizer = nlp.get_pipe('textcat')
scores = text_categorizer.predict(test_docs)
predicted_labels = scores.argmax(axis=1)
```

I've created the model from scratch with just the TextCategorizer layer (following the space 3.0 guidelines). By doing this, the documents have no `.vector` attribute.

this is my config.cfg

```
[nlp]
lang = "it"
pipeline = ["textcat"]
disabled = []
before_creation = null
after_creation = null
after_pipeline_creation = null
batch_size = 1000
tokenizer = {"@tokenizers":"spacy.Tokenizer.v1"}

[components]

[components.textcat]
factory = "textcat"
scorer = {"@scorers":"spacy.textcat_scorer.v1"}
threshold = 0.5

[components.textcat.model]
@architectures = "spacy.TextCatEnsemble.v2"
nO = null

[components.textcat.model.linear_model]
@architectures = "spacy.TextCatBOW.v2"
exclusive_classes = true
ngram_size = 1
no_output_layer = false
nO = null

[components.textcat.model.tok2vec]
@architectures = "spacy.Tok2Vec.v2"
...
```

Answer (score 2):

In SpaCy you can use `.vector` to get the vector representation of a document.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc1 = nlp("I like apples.")
doc2 = nlp("I like bananas.")
doc3 = nlp("The book is about quantum physics.")
print(doc1.vector)
> [-0.28571516 ... 0.77876693]
print(doc2.vector)
> [ 3.14834714e-02 ... 5.22061586e-01]
print(doc3.vector)
> [ 0.08713525 ... 0.2642293 ]
```

Visualize these vectors for example by using PCA in sklearn to reduce the dimensions to two, then create a basic plot:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

pca_ = PCA(n_components=2).fit_transform(numpy.array([doc.vector for doc in [doc1, doc2, doc3]]))
pca_x = tsne_x = [x_[0] for x_ in pca_]
pca_y = [x_[1] for x_ in pca_]
ax = plt.gca()
plt.scatter(pca_x, pca_y, alpha=0.25)
ax.set_xlim([-3, 3])
ax.set_ylim([-3, 3])
for i, name in enumerate(["doc1", "doc2", "doc3"]):
    text = ax.annotate(name, (pca_x[i], pca_y[i]))
plt.show()
```

Which will give you:

[image]

I am not sure if this exactly what you meant though, if you do not mean the generic vector representation of each document but the feature vectors or something similar you can do the same thing and use that instead of `.vector`. Of course by reducing the dimensions you will not be able see the individual vector values in the plot afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, but I created the nlp model from scratch with just the TextCategorizer layer (following the spacy guidelines). By doing this, the doc has no vector!. I'll update the question

Comment: I see, I personally never did text classification with SpaCy so I'm not sure what exactly are the fields available in the final processed docs, but you could see if something like [.embed or .encode](https://spacy.io/api/architectures#Tok2Vec) works for you. You can pool the token-level vectors into a document-level vector by calculating their average. Or you try to see if you can get vectors somewhere out of the [TextCatEnsemble](https://spacy.io/api/architectures#TextCatEnsemble) or [TextCatBOW](https://spacy.io/api/architectures#TextCatBOW) attributes.